# Solidity: How to initialize an array within a struct, passed as a parameter?

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract A{
    struct N{
        string any;
        uint256[] numberArray;
    }

    N[] public numbers;

    function init(uint256[] _numbers) public{
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _numbers.length; i++) {
            uint256[] memory arr;
            arr[0] = _numbers[i];
            numbers.push(N("anything", arr));
        }
    }
}
```

This contract compiles but throws:

`transact to A.init errored: VM error: invalid opcode.
invalid opcode The execution might have thrown.`

What I wish to achieve

**Example call:**

```
init([1,2,3,4,5])
```

**Outcome:**

```
N[0] = "anything", [1]

N[1] = "anything", [2]

N[2] = "anything", [3]

N[3] = "anything", [4]

N[4] = "anything", [5]
```

Afterwards I would like to be able to push to the array within the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the declaration of `arr` arry. I think you should specify the array's length.

This following code works fine:

```
function init(uint256[]   _numbers) public{


   for (uint256 i = 0; i < _numbers.length; i++) {

       uint256[] memory arr=new uint256[](_numbers.length);//<===as you're using only arr[0] you can use different size (exp 1).

       arr[0]= _numbers[i];
      numbers.push(N("anything", arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work. Can I then add a function that will push additional elements to the array? Or is it fixed size even tho it's now in storage?

Comment: you're already using only an array (arr) with a  single element why do you care about size? BTW if it works consider to accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, you answer pretty much helped to solve the problem. I tried on the function for adding more variables to the array later on.
function addNumberAtIndex(uint index, uint number) public {
            numbers[index].numberArray.push(number);
        }

Would be great to include it into your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Senju happy to hear that you can edit my answer and add your function. I request that because i don't know where addNumberAtIndex will be used

Comment: Actually your answer fully answers the questions. Adding further numbers into the array was just my continuous approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found some of the logic strange so I started breaking it down. I'm not 100% sure I solved what you want or just over-simplified it.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract A{

    struct N{
        string any;
        uint[] numberArray;
    }

    N[] public numbers;

    function init(uint[] _numbers) public{
        numbers.push(N("anything", _numbers));
    }

    function getNumbersAtIndex(uint index) public view returns(uint[] _numbers) {
        return numbers[index].numberArray;
    }

}
```

The extra function is so you can inspect it.

At the risk of straying a little off topic, there is a risk of gas cost increase and a scaling limit. To avoid that, refactor or add functions to pass info in and get it out one element at a time.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think it's over-simplified since I you are adding the whole array to one struct element. I tried to update the question to make my expectations more clear.